# Unable to push my own image to a registration repository

Tags: docker, push, dockerhub

I am a docker beginner. I would like to share an image with a friend. Thus,
I went to docker website and notice that I could share it with an organization . So i created it , but now i'm not able to copy my images from my own file to the organisation repository .

the result of `docker images` is :

> jeremyy55/noe effectif 0cfac8651387 .....

the organisation name is "rekcodpyth" and the repository name is "lefameux".

I tried to type :

`docker push  rekcodpyth/lefameux/0cfac8651387`

but it tells me:

> An image does not exist locally with the tag:
>   rekcodpyth/lefameux/0cfac8651387

can someone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you haven't created a tag, so docker doesn't know what to push.

Try with

```
docker tag 0cfac8651387 lefameux/effectif:<version>
docker push lefameux/effectif:<version>
```

Or, if organization is your host

```
docker tag 0cfac8651387 rekcodpyth/lefameux/effectif:<version>
docker push rekcodpyth/lefameux/effectif:<version>
```